# gulp-sass не транслирует файлы без конкретного пути app/sass/**/*.sass

Tags: gulp, sass

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'), // Подключаем Gulp
    sass = require('gulp-sass'); //Подключаем Sass пакет

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});
```

При указании конкретного пути к файлу app/sass/main.sass, все работает отлично, так же работает app/sass/**/*.scss

Comment: "gulp-sass не транслирует файлы без конкретного пути app/sass/**/*.sass" .... ".... так же работает app/sass/**/*.scss"

Определитесь, что все же не работает.

Comment: app/sass/**/*.sass -так не работает, app/sass/**/*.scss - а так работает, нужен 1-й вариант

Comment: ну так расширения у файлов должны быть тогда `.sass` + в опциях есть параметр `indentedSyntax`